# how to create a jena Model not in-memory?

Tags: java, jena

I'm trying to create a `Model` in jena that won't load the entire data into memory but instead will read from the filesystem.

I found a whole lot of available configurations, but they all seem to be in-memory (for example on `OntModelSpec`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Apache Jena TDB - see [documentation here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/index.html).

TDB stores your dataset on disk, but accesses it very efficiently: you shouldn't experience any real performance difference over an in-memory model.

Typically, if I'm dealing with a large model or dataset I work like this:

1. Load model on commandline:

   ```
   # /tmp/DB is where TDB will store the indexed model
   $ tdbloader2 --loc /tmp/DB file.nt
   ```

(use `tdbloader` on Windows)

2. (Optional) Try a query:

   ```
   $ tdbquery --loc /tmp/DB @query.sparql
   ```
3. Access like any old model from java:

   ```
   Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset("/tmp/DB") ;
   Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel() ;
   ... continue as before ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own implementation of org.apache.jena.graph.Graph, which won't work with memory.
An example is [d2rq](https://github.com/d2rq/d2rq), where de.fuberlin.wiwiss.d2rq.jena.GraphD2RQ works with databases. but it is based on outdated jena.

Comment: I was hoping for something built-in... seems like there should be somewhere if they *always* mention that it's in-mem.